# Get server machine name in HTML or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, apache

Something which I though was supposed to be simpler is getting me some headache.

Just need that my webserver with Apache installed shows me the virtual machine name:

Something like `echo $HOSTNAME` in the index.html displayed on the principal page.

I read something about doing it with JS and I did so with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var servername = location.host;
    alert(servername);
</script>
```

But this will show me the servernmae, which is configured in Apache conf (hello.com).

But I need just the virtual machine name. Also the location (it's a VM in Azure)

Is there anyway in HTML or JavaScript to display information from variables in the page?

like `"echo $VARIABLE"`

thanks

Comment: given that HTML and JS are parsed and executed client side, running on your user's computer, not your VM: no. However, your _server_ might be able to pull that information from somewhere, in which case you'll need to template that into your page response. Whether it can do that or not is something you should do some web searching for.

Comment: I have a curl command to an API that we have, that when  you execute it,  you get server machine name. Is there a way of getting that curl command in some button in the page and hitting that button to obtain the server virtual machine name with JS?. If not is there a way of putting that curl inside the html file and execute it dynamically?

Comment: "curl" is a command line utility that has nothing to do with browsers, so it's the irrelevant part: the API is the part that matters. As long as that API is web-accessible and talks HTTP (e.g. it can respond with a properly formatted bit of JSON, with the correct HTTP headers) then any client-side JS can get the information from it.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are trying to output the hostname of your instance while you put you instance IP in browser. I did it for my RHEL machine hosted on AWS.

Steps to do it are:

- Make sure you have php installed on your server (`yum install -y php`).
- Create a file name /var/www/html/index.php  and paste below content to it.

  ```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>  
    <body>
      <p><?php echo "hostname is:".gethostname(); ?></p>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- Hit your instance IP to browser and you should be able to see your hostname.